# Broken ROS hydro configuration

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After during a system update this morning my ROS configuration is not valid anymore. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and hydro.

My config is as follows (which used to work..):

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash    # <-- ROS HYDRO
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:/some/path:/some/other/path
export ROS_WORKSPACE=/some/path
# Catkin workspace 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
# MoveIT setup  (i installed from source..)
source ~/moveit/devel/setup.bash # <-- Using the source installation of moveit
# More modifications modifications
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:~/more/folders
```

As said this used to work, but not anymore. I now have to source my hydro setup manually (added it again as the final step in my bashrc file).

Any ideas of what caused this change? Am i doing something wrong in my configuration steps?

This is what is shown when running roscore

```
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosversion", line 85, in <module>
    version = rosstack.get_stack_version(stack_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 377, in get_stack_version
    return get_stack_version_by_dir(self.get_path(stack))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 165, in get_path
    self._update_location_cache()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 148, in _update_location_cache
    list_by_path(self._manifest_name, path, cache)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 63, in list_by_path
    root = ElementTree(None, os.path.join(d, PACKAGE_FILE))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 611, in __init__
    self.parse(file)
  File "<string>", line 38, in parse
cElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 53, column 2
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
```

Env | grep ROS gives:

```
$ env | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/xxxx/moveit/src:/home/xxxx/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks:/home/xxxx/ros_stacks:/home/xxxx/youbot/youbot_driver
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://127.0.0.1:11311
ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR=/home/xxxx/moveit/build/test_results
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/xxxx/moveit/devel/share/common-lisp:/home/xxxx/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=hydro
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85276/broken-ros-hydro-configuration/) by [Rasmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/6846/rasmus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-30**:
What is "not working" exactly? What environment variables are set? Some of the other setup.bash that you are sourcing might overwrite things.

**Comment by [Rasmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/6846/rasmus/) on 2013-09-30**:
I just updated the Question. What puzzles me is that it worked on Friday.. But after an update this morning something went wrong.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-30**:
Did the system update also update ROS pacakges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay so this was a stupid typo in a package.xml file. I must have edited it as the last thing Friday. I corrected it and all works fine.
Sorry

---

Originally posted by [Rasmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/6846/rasmus/) with karma: 58 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l_a_den](https://answers.ros.org/users/17996/l_a_den/) on 2014-05-14**:
Can you tell me how you solve the problem? Because I encounter the same problem.

**Comment by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on 2015-01-03**:
This is due to some syntax error in your package.xml. For me, I accidentaly hit enter in one line and broke a commented line into an uncommented one with syntax errors. After fixing this, I could run roscore again.